# SpeechSynthesizer in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, speechsynthesizer

I am developing a app to convert text to speech using speech Synthesizer in windows phone 8. In that I want to highlight text which has been spoken by speech Synthesizer. In MSDN site it is given that GetCurrentlySpokenPrompt() method is available in speechSynthesizer class, but in my code no such method is accessible.

here's my code:

```
SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
IAsyncAction task= synth.SpeakTextAsync("text");
var spokenText = synth.GetCurrentlySpokenPrompt(); // here its giving error
```

can anyone help me!

Comment: Avoid assuming that a computer that fits in your pocket is anything like the one that's on your desktop.  Use the [class properly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.aspx), the MSDN article clearly shows that this method is not available.

Comment: actually I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx this link. here its clearly given that it supports windows phone 8 platform. can you tell me where it given that this method is not available?

Comment: Click on the link I gave you.  Here it is again: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.aspx

Comment: I was talking about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx this link. anyways what is solution then? can't we do this?

Comment: `here its giving error` is not helpful. What's the given error/exception?

Comment: my question itself says this method is not available, so error is obviously "it does not contain definition for GetCurrentlySpokenPrompt()"!

Answer (score 1):

`WP 8` and `WP 8.1` have limited functionality and limited sets of api's. I may think it will not be possible in `WP`. Check out the msdn link for help [Text-to-speech (TTS) for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207057%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)